# Getting Ruby and MySQL to work together

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to install ROR with a MySQL backend on a Windows 7 x64 box but they are not working together. When I did this before several months ago, it was just a mysql install and a bundle command but not this time.

I've installed MySQL 5.1 32 bit on a path with no spaces and configured the server. I had to install the mysql2 gem using the command line arguments to specify the mysql instance path to get the gem to install. However, rake db:create fails with a `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)` error.

I have verifed that mysql is running on the specified port. mysql, mysqladmin, and `telnet localhost 3306` all work as normal. I have a firewall exception for port 3306 and it works fine. I've also turned the firewall off and it makes no difference.

I've spent hours going though google and trying many possibilities without success. Most of the documentation I have found relates to issues where mysql is not running / running on a pipe but this is not my problem.

```
database.yml excerpt:
common: &common
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  #host: 127.0.0.1
  host: localhost
  port: 3307


development:
  <<: *common
  database: project_dev
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: try connecting to it in a cmd line (black dos window) with this to verify anything can connect to it: mysql -u root -p

Then it will ask you for password. If that connects, the problem is with your ruby setup that can't find the server. if you can't get in either, it is a mysql problem. May at least help you find the issue.

Comment: I was trying a couple of ports: 3306 and 3307 to make sure it wasn't a port config problem. Neither works.

Comment: mysql -u root -p works just fine. same with mysqladmin -u root -p version and telnet localhost 3306.

Answer (score 0):

From the [mysql2 page on GitHub](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2), you may have a missing configuration line in your Gemfile, depending on your version of ActiveRecord.

> NOTE: as of 0.3.0, and ActiveRecord 3.1 - the ActiveRecord adapter has been pulled out of this gem and into ActiveRecord itself. If you need to use mysql2 with Rails versions < 3.1 make sure and specify gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7" in your Gemfile

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have active record 3.1.3 and mysql2 0.3.11 specified in gemfile.lock. I'm using ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.1.3, mysql 5.1.61